# Anapanasati and Compassion

Tags: anapanasati, metta

I'm wondering basically whether anapanasati can *result* in as much compassion as metta. Though the focus is different, **can these two meditations have the same potential for altruism? Does meditating on the breath produce as much compassion?**

Basically, I wonder if -- in order to become altruistic and compassionate -- one has to *focus* on compassion as a subject, or if that is not necessary.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Anapanasati, when practised properly, arises from compassion towards onself.

Therefore, when Anapanasati is fulfilled, the defilements end, peace occurs & the original compassion towards oneself remains; which then manifests outwardly in one's natural state of being.

To practise the Dhamma and Anapanasati successfully requires a great act love towards oneself.

This love will remain when the task is completed.

However, Anapanasati cannot be practised & fulfilled if we continue to engage in behaviours (kamma) that defile, enslave & weaken our self and others.